# If else method giving unexpected result

Tags: python-3.x

```
m = 5
if m == 1 or 4:
    print("x") 
else:
    print("y")
```

I want this code to print y, not x.

Comment: I don't see a reason to downvote the question. Sure, an advanced programmer, who can parse Python in their head the same way the Python parser can, will be able to spot the error. There is no need to punish people for not (yet) knowing things.

Answer (score 4):

`4` evaluates to true, hence the result

```
m = 5
if m == 1 or m == 4:
    print("x") 
else:
    print("y")
```

[Fiddle](http://tpcg.io/7vVeXf)

Answer (score 2):

A number except for zero is an implicit True.
Read up on [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

What you've written actually translates to:

```py
m = 5
if (m == 1) or True:
    print("x") 
else:
    print("y")
```

Your `if` will always be True.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
if m == 1 or m == 4:
```

instead.